# Can't get rid of leading zeros on y axis

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to plot graphs in Matplotlib and embed them into pyqt5 GUI. Everything is working fine, except for the fact that my y axis has loads of leading zeros which I cannot seem to get rid of.

I have tried googling how to format the axis, but nothing seems to work! I can't set the ticks directly because there's no way of determining what they will be, as I am going to be working with varying sized data sets.

```py
num_bins = 50

# create an axis
ax = self.figure.add_subplot(111)

# discards the old graph
ax.clear()

##draws the bars and legend
colours = ['blue','red']
ax.hist(self.histoSets, num_bins, density=True, histtype='bar', color=colours, label=colours)
ax.legend(prop={'size': 10})


##set x ticks
min,max = self.getMinMax()
scaleMax = math.ceil((max/10000))*10000
scaleMin = math.floor((min/10000))*10000
scaleRange = scaleMax - scaleMin
ax.xaxis.set_ticks(np.arange(scaleMin, scaleMax+1, scaleRange/4))


# refresh canvas
self.draw()
```

[image]

Comment: You can add `self.figure.tight_layout()` to see the ticks in completeness.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

all those numbers on your y-axis are tiny, i.e. on the order of 1e-5.  this is because the integral of the density is defined to be 1 and your x-axis spans such a large range

I can mostly reproduce your plot with:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

y = np.random.normal([190000, 220000], 20000, (5000, 2))

a, b, c = plt.hist(y, 40, density=True)
```

giving me:

[image: above plot]

the tuple returned from [`hist`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.hist.html) contains useful information, notably the first element (`a` above) are the densities, and the second element (`b` above) are the bins that it picked.  you can see this all sums to one by doing:

```
sum(a[0] * np.diff(b))
```

and getting 1 back.

as ImportanceOfBeingErnest says you can use [`tight_layout()`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.tight_layout.html) to resize the plot if it doesn't fit into the area

Comment: Oh wow! I didn't realize that was the problem. I feel a bit silly now, but thank you everybody for your help!

Comment: well it might have been nice @ProgrammingDucky if you had marked this as the solution so Sam could get a few SO Kudos ;)

Comment: @DennisJensen  meh, you win some you lose some! :)

Comment: Kind of new to this site, so sorry if it takes me a while to get up to speed!